# Can't set right alt + shift to switch language repeatedly

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, language-support

I successfully managed to get <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> to swich languages. However when I use the left <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> key combination to switch languages I can do it repeatedly to go back and forth between languages, but this is not the case with the right side of the keyboard.
How can I get right <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> to behave the same as the left side combination?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is your OS? if you r using GNOME right Alt generally is a modifier key.. you need to remove it to achieve what you r looking for.. what's the output of `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options`

Comment: Thanks for your response. I believe I am using Unity. Here's the output of the command: `['grp:alt_shift_toggle']`

Comment: Did you manage to solve this problem? If not, then what are the languages you are using? From top bar, first set the active language to a **non-English** language and then click on the "Show Keyboard Layout" in the same menu. What is the name shown on the "Right Alt" key in keyboard layout?

Comment: can you press the right shift with left alt ? does it change the layout ?

Comment: @BasilBattikhi Yes, it does loop when using the left alt with the right shift.

Comment: In XFCE I was have to remove these setting from `settings Editor`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem occurs because "Right Alt" is used as "3rd level chooser key", to solve this problem :

- open Tweaks (you can get it from Ubuntu Software Center)
- select "Keyboard & Mouse"
- select "Additional Layout Options"
- select "Key to choose the 3rd Level"
- choose "Right Alt never chooses 3rd level"

you can assign another key as 3rd level chooser if you still need to access those keys

Comment: thanks i edited the answer